# Making a sass (scss) based grid - how to create a list of class names with one declaration

Tags: css, sass, grid-layout, compass-sass

So I'm creating a very simple grid and want to limit the amount of repeated declarations.

My Scss grid

```
$columns: 12;
$margin: 10;
$max-width: 1200;

// do not edit these values
$layout-margin-width: $max-width + $margin * 2;
$percent-margin: $margin / $layout-margin-width;

// Grid Container
.main {
    max-width: $max-width + px;
    margin: 0 auto;
        &:before,
        &:after {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

// Grid Columns
@for $i from 1 through $columns {
    .grid-#{$i} {
        width: ( ($i / $columns) - 2 * $percent-margin) * 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 $percent-margin * 100%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Which outputs to

```
.main { max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; }
.main:before, .main:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }

.grid-1 { width: 6.69399%; padding: 0; margin: 0 0.81967%; float: left; }

//

.grid-12 { width: 98.36066%; padding: 0; margin: 0 0.81967%; float: left; }
```

That creates a lot of repeating CSS so I'd like to be able to have a list the grid class names together and have float:left etc in a single declaration, like this

```
.grid-1,
.grid-2,
//
.grid-12 {
    float:left;
    //other declarations
}
```

How do I structure the Scss loop to do this?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to find what I was looking for but couldnt come up with anything

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this using `@extend`.

**Example**

```
%grid {
   float:left;
}

@for $i from 1 through $columns {
    .grid-#{$i} {
        width: ( ($i / $columns) - 2 * $percent-margin) * 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 $percent-margin * 100%;
        @extend: %grid;
    }
}
```

This will then output your css like this.

```
.grid-1,
.grid-2,
.grid-3 {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks. The colon after @extend shouldn't be there though